# Calculate the amout that should be added or subtracted to x and y axis with rotation?

Tags: vector, coordinates

Say I have this figure[image]:

How would I calculate the amount I must add or subtract to x and y axis to get the cube to move in the direction its facing? The rotation is a float 0 - 360 and 0 is straight up.

Comment: Is the 40° measured counter-clockwise from the right (positive z-axis), as is the mathematical convention? Or are you using a different angle convention?

Comment: It is measured clockwise as a float 0 - 360.f

Comment: 0 being straight up?

Comment: Yes, 0 is straight up

Comment: If you created this diagram in MS Paint, there's a text option where you can type letters rather than drawing them by hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a coordinate system with:

- `y+` pointing up
- `x+` pointing right
- `angle` measured clockwise from straight up

Then a unit vector pointing in the direction given by a particular `angle` has:

```
u.x = sin(angle)
u.y = cos(angle)
```

Assuming you're careful to convert between degrees & radians or other units as needed for the particular trig library you're using (most work in radians, some work in degrees, some work in fractions of a full circle, etc.)

To move more or less than one unit in this direction, just apply a scalar multiple to both axes:

```
v.x = distance * sin(angle)
v.y = distance * cos(angle)
```

Comment: This is pretty foundational trig & vector algebra, so you might find you get a lot of benefit by taking a quick web course on the topics, eg. on [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry/unit-circle-trig-func) or [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjBOesZCoqc&list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab)

Comment: And if you can render the cube, you should be able to move it, since the displacement from "back" to "front" is the same direction as moving "forward".